# error 10 at 0 depth lookup:certificate has expired

Tags: openssl, homebrew

When I try have `brew install openssl`, I got the following error:

```
error 10 at 0 depth lookup:certificate has expired
```

I searched, but not found any solution. Someone knows the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this Google query](https://www.google.com/search?q=error%2010%20at%200%20depth%20lookup%3acertificate%20has%20expired) I was able to find a [ticket on Homebrew repository](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/22440) with exactly the same error message.

I assume the issue is some conflict with XCode. Make sure you are using the latest XCode version and update all Homebrew formula before running the command.

Comment: I'm already latest xcode version and upodate all homebrew formula.
=/

Comment: Then you may want to open a ticket at Homebrew providing your system details. It may be an issue with the formula.